# What might prevent a "child-removed" event from firing?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Consider the following (simplified) code:

```
var queueTask = function (taskObject) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // Create new task reference & push new Task object to reference location
    var newTaskRef = firebase.database().ref("task").push(taskObject);

    newTaskRef.once('child_removed', function (snapshot) {
        // SUCCESS
        console.log("@DEBUG - TASK COMPLETE/CHILD REMOVED");
        deferred.resolve(snapshot);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

(A server-side worker processes the task, writes the result to another location on the database, then deletes the object.)

The Task object is deleted, but the `child-removed` event never fires.

What might prevent a `child-removed` event from firing?

Comment: My initial assumption is that, the task is being performed too quickly.

Comment: I've eliminated the processing time as a factor: I added an artificial delay to the task worker processing code, however, the result is the same: The `on-removed` event never fires.

Comment: Also, I've added task to a non-root location (`.../queue/task/`) but that didn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: I'm pretty confident it's something simple, but the error is escaping me somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check the Security Rules:**

If your Security Rules are left at the following default value, Event queries will not work:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
  }
}
```

Also if your Security Rules do not allow read-access on the location the data was written to (i.e. User has  write-access but not read-access) Event queries will fail.

Event queries return a snapshot of the changed data (deleted data in the case of the `child_removed` Event) so, having read-access is necessary.